# Question about injection on an unbounded space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

I have this space $$C_0((0,+\infty))=\left\lbrace u,u\in C((0,+\infty)),\lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} u(t)=0\right\rbrace$$ with the norm $$||u||_{\infty}=\sup_{t\geq0}|u(t)|$$

how to prove that $C_0((0,+\infty))\hookrightarrow L^2((0,\infty))$ (continuous injection).

Please

Thank you.

Comment: Before wondering about continuity, did you check that the inclusion really holds?

Comment: no i can't prove it ?

Comment: how to do @DavideGiraudo please

Comment: To define that norme, you need to guarantee somehow that the functions are bounded.

Comment: @ajotatxe i don't understand

Comment: There are continuous function which vanish at infinity and are not square integrable. For example, $f(x)=x$ on $(0,1)$ and $1/x$ on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: so this injection is not correct !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before asking for continuity, we have to check whether the inclusion holds. It's not the case, because the function defined by 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\mbox{ if }x\in (0,1),\\
\frac 1{\sqrt x}&\mbox{ if }x\in (1,+\infty),
\end{cases}$$
is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, its limit at infinity is $0$, but $f^2$ is not integrable.

Comment: thank you, can you polease told me if there is a hilbert space sucht that $C_0((0,+\infty))$ is contuously injective ?

Comment: Maybe this could be asked in an other question, with the motivations. (I guess you are looking for non-trivial examples, that is, infinite dimensional ones).

Comment: @Vrouvrou: For example, $L^2((0, \infty), \mu)$ with $\mu$ a *finite* measure.